# Let $G$ be a finite solvable group, all of whose Sylow subgroups are abelian. Prove that $Z(G) \cap G' = 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite solvable group, all of whose Sylow subgroups are abelian. Prove that $Z(G) \cap G' = 1$.

**Attempt:** From the second isomorphism theorem $\frac{G'}{Z(G)\cap G'} \simeq \frac{G'Z(G)}{Z(G)}$ so it suffices to show that $\frac{G'Z(G)}{Z(G)} \simeq G'$. I couldn't proceed any further though and I can't figure out how to use the fact that every Sylow subgroup is abelian. Any hint is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If this is from a lecture course or book, what sort of theorems about soluble groups do you have? What sort of theorems about groups with abelian Sylow $p$-subgroups do you have?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven It's from an exercise sheet I found while googling around. In my lecture notes only basic aspects are covered (solvable series and derived series). I think it's possible that it requires some stronger results with which I may not be familiar (like the Frattini subgroup).

Comment: This is an exercise from Dietrich Burde's group theory course, by the looks of it. His lecture notes are also available on his website.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thanks. I'll take a look at them and come back if I am still stuck.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I'm still pretty much stuck. A hint, particularly on how to use the fact that all Sylow groups are abelian, would be very helpful.

Comment: This result is due to Taunt and appears on p. 289 of Robinson's book. You need a little bit of transfer theory to get it, but maybe it can be done without transfer.

Comment: @the_fox Thanks so much. It definitely is way harder than it initially looks!

Comment: I don't know if it can be done without transfer. I couldn't think of a way. The clues that transfer might be needed are $G'$ and abelian Sylows. When you see those two together there's a good chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the result is false, then there is a prime $p$ dividing $|Z(G) \cap G'|$. Let $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$. Then an element of order $p$ in $Z(G) \cap G'$ lies in $P$, so $Z(G) \cap G' \cap P \ne 1$.

Consider the transfer homomorphism $\tau:G \to P/P'$ which, since $P$ is abelian, can be taken to be $\tau:G \to P$.

Now it is easy to see from the definition of $\tau$ that, for $g \in Z(G)$, we have $\tau(g) = g^k$, where $k := |G:P|$ is coprime to $p$. So $\tau$ restricted to $Z(G) \cap P$ is injective, but on the other hand ${\rm Im}(\tau)$ is abelian, so if $g \in G'$ then $\tau(g)=1$.

So $Z(G) \cap P \cap G' = 1$, contrary to assumption.

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks. I'm not familiar with transfers but I will certainly read about them and try to understand the solution fully.

Comment: I am wondering if there might be a proof which does not appeal to the transfer homomorphism and its basic properties. (Otherwise, why restrict to soluble groups?)

Comment: @the_fox Yes, good point! This solution does not use solubility. On the other hand, the basic theory of the transfer homomorphism is really not excessively difficult, so it seems unnecessary to go to great lengths to avoid using it.

Comment: And why are we assuming that $G$ needs to be solvable? Without that it is still true. So, would that, solvabilty, hint to a transferless proof?

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, here is a different proof based on character theory of groups. The transfer map is most of the time reflected in the *determinant* of (a representation affording) an irreducible character.

**Theorem** Let $P \in Syl_p(G)$, then $G' \cap Z(G) \cap P \subseteq P'$.

**Proof** Choose a linear character $\lambda \in Irr(P)$ and $g \in G' \cap Z(G) \cap P$. We are going to show that $\lambda(g)=1$. Since $P'=\bigcap \{ker(\lambda) : \lambda \in Irr(P), \lambda(1)=1\}$, this will guarantee the result. 
Now, $\lambda^G=\sum a_{\chi}\chi$, for certain $\chi \in Irr(G)$ and $a_{\chi}$ positive integers. Since $\lambda^G(1)=|G:P|=\sum a_{\chi}\chi(1)$ is not divisible by $p$, there must be a constituent $\chi$ of $\lambda^G$ with $p \nmid \chi(1)$. Let $\mathfrak{X}$ be a representation affording this character $\chi$. 
Since $g \in Z(G)$, $\mathfrak{X}(g)=\omega I$ for certain $\omega \in \mathbb{C}^*$. Note that the order of $\omega$ (in $\mathbb{C}^*$) is a divisor of the order of $g$, which is a power of $p$, since $g \in P$. But $g \in G'$, so $det(\mathfrak{X}(g))=det(\omega I)=\omega^{\chi(1)}=1$. So the order of $\omega$ divides also $\chi(1)$. We conclude that $\omega=1$, and hence $g \in ker(\mathfrak{X})=ker(\chi)$. By Frobenius Reciprocity, $\chi_P=a_{\chi}\lambda + \cdots$, whence $ker(\chi_P)=P \cap ker(\chi) \subseteq ker(\lambda)$. So $g \in ker(\lambda)$ and we are done.

Your assertion, that all $P$ are abelian, now implies that no prime divides the order of the normal subgroup $G' \cap Z(G)$, so it must be trivial. Note that we do not need *solvability* of the group and that the condition that all Sylow-subgroups are abelian does not imply that $G$ is solvable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The exercise was given as is in an introductory group theory course (by the looks of the lecture notes). I believe that the extra assumption that $G$ is solvable is supposed to make the exercise easier or at least solvable with tools that were taught in this course however I still can't come up with a solution using only methods from the lecture notes.

Comment: I will keep thinking of a proof with induction on the order of $G$…

Comment: If we consider a minimal counterexample $G$ then $G'Z(G)/Z(G) \cap Z(G/Z(G)) = 1$ but I don't know if we can conclude that $G'Z(G)/Z(G)=1$ from that alone.

Comment: That's so neat! (+1)

Comment: Thanks @Deif, for letting me know. Appreciated.